# PHP function not writing to file correctly, leaving out a select field

Tags: php

So I've got a form that is sending to an email **and** writing to a file.  However, it is leaving out one of the select fields.  Funny because it picks up the other select field just fine and I replicated it.  It's leaving out the Contact field ($contact, How was the contact made?).  Any ideas?

HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" id="serivce_form">
        <p>Submitter Name :&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="submitter_name" /></p>
        <p>Name :&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="name" /></p> 
        <p>Time :&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="time" /></p>
        <p>Date :&nbsp; 
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" /></p>
        <p>How was the contact made? </p> 
            <select name="contact" size="1">
                <option selected value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                <option value="email">Email</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        <p>Phone :&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="phone" /></p> 
        <p>Email :&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="email" /></p> 
        <p>How did you hear about us? </p>
            <select name="source" size="1">
                <option selected value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="online">Online</option>
                <option value="client referral">Client Referral</option>
                <option value="non client referral">Non Client Referral</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        <br />
        <p>Experience :&nbsp; </p>
            <select name="experience" size="1">
                <option selected value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="Praise">Praise</option>
                <option value="Compliment">Compliment</option>
                <option value="New Client">New Client</option>
                <option value="Existing Client Maintenance">Existing Client Maintenance</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        <br />

        <p>Message :&nbsp; </p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
        $submitter_name = $_POST['submitter_name'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $contact = $_POST['contact'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $source = $_POST['source'];
        $experience = $_POST['experience'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];


        $from_name = 'Form Name';
        $from = 'email@email.com';
        $to = 'email2@email.com';
        $subject = 'Subject';
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers = "From: ".$from .  "\r\nFrom: ".$from_name." <".$from.">\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $message_top = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" .
            "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

            $email_message = "\n"."Submitter Name: $submitter_name<br />
                    Name: $name<br />
                    Time: $time<br />
                    Date: $date<br />
                    How was the contact made? $contact<br />
                    Phone: $phone<br />
                    Email: $email<br />
                    How did you hear about us? $source<br />
                    Experience: $experience<br />
                    Message: $message<br />";

        $email_message = stripslashes($email_message);
        $email_message = str_replace("\n","\r\n",$email_message);
        $email_message = $message_top . $email_message;

      mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
        echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Go back</a>";

    //TO FILE
            $message = str_replace(",","",$message);
            $content = "\n$submitter_name,$name,$time,$date,$contact,$phone,$email,$source,$experience,$message";

            $f = fopen("lw_service_log.txt", "a");
            fwrite($f, $content);
            fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: what does `size=1` mean in `select` tag?

Comment: size=1 essentially forces a dropdown for the selection. Otherwise if I had say size=4, it would stretch the window to show all 4 options at once.

Comment: What is displayed when you do `var_dump($_POST['contact']);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the option value names in the html happened to have the same value as some other bits.  Creating unique ones for them seemed to fix it.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.  Check for something overwriting the variable elsewhere in your code - I presume you have cut some bits out before pasting.